# Trouble OO design 666

Tags: oop

I am writing an application which is dealing with expressions. So I defined an abstract class.

```
abstract public class Expression
```

There are various types of expressions, for example

```
public class Variable extends Expression
public class Constant extends Expression
```

and so on.

I want to create this expressions based on input strings, so for example if
the input is 'x1' I want to create a variable, if input is '12' I want to create a number. 
So far so good. But there is a problem. How to implement this "creation" in terms of OO? I mean I don't want to create a method with `switch` and check cases (is the input string a number, or maybe a variable, or + or * or...).
If I will create a new Expression type class I rely don't want to go to this "creation method" each single time and add a new case to deal with the new type. Is anyone has an idea how to do this?

PS If my English is incorrect, please forgive me :)

Comment: I suspect that somewhere there will have to be a factory which examines the input and conditionally returns the constructed type, and that condition would take the form of an `if/else` chain or a `switch` or some sort.  It sounds like you're trying to replace a conditional with polymorphism, but that's meant to address objects which already exist.  It doesn't really help for objects yet to be created.

Comment: So sad... :( Are you sure there is not other way to do it "my way"?

Comment: For example each class has a static metod pattern (for example regex) and there is an object with a set of pairs (pattern, constructor)? But is it possible to create in java array of constructors?

Comment: A regex?  An array of constructors?  What exactly are you trying to achieve here?  It sounds like you're vastly over-complicating things, but for what purpose?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to achieve this, what I've described above. I've asked a question and people are answering like, well, you should do it that way, but  I want to do it in my way (I mean described above). So again: Is there a way to do it in my way? Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: Generally, when the question is "I know how to do something the right way, but I want to do it some really weird wrong way instead" then you're probably on your own.  We can help with actual problems, but not made-up ones that don't make sense to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is traditionally realized through a [factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) class or method, which is exactly what you described with:

> a method with switch and check cases (is the input string a number,
>   or maybe a variable, or + or * or...)

It would then be called like this:

```
Expression a = ExpressionFactory.getExpression(someString);
```

[Little example code to get the idea](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNTF5ZWVEQ2xXVjg)

Why exactly do you think this is an invalid aproach?

Comment: Is there a problem with my answer? Can I improve it somehow?

Comment: I did not click the -1 button, but look, i don't want to have a switch expression. Suppose I want to add a complex number, and complex logarithm. I don't want to go to this switch-string-checking method :( I want independence :(

Comment: @Maciej why do you think this will break encapsulation? The code that parses the complex number should not be in the factory anyways. If you create an `ExpressionParser` that analyses the `string` and returns an `enum` that in turn gets checked in the `ExpressionFactory` switch, every component of your design will be easily extendable and well encapsulated in their own classes, each with well defined responsabilities, which is exactly your goal in object oriented design.

Comment: Ok, sorry for hassle.

Comment: @Maciej No worries. But do you see the benefits now yourself?

Comment: No, I see a benefits of my approach, I don't see the benefits of "factory" approach :( I know what I want to say, but I don't know the way to do it :( this is sad.

Comment: @Maciej Check out my last edit. Maybe the code will help you see how nicely everything is separated and encapsulated :)